# How can I hide the keyboard indicator from the panel?

Tags: release-freya, keyboard

I installed indicator-synapse before adding the unstable repository and it didn't install the search app, it installed something about the keyboard instead. Then I added the unstable repo and installed synapse again and the search app is there but I can't remove the keyboard thing. Could you help me removing it?

it's the little [Es] icon which appeared after I installed indicator-synapse without the unstable repo

[image: The [Es] icon]

Answer (score 6):

Ok, I solved it!

- install [DConf-Tools](http://howtoelementaryos.org/how-to-install-dconf-tools-in-elementary-os) `sudo apt-get install dconf-tools`
- browse: **com > canonical > indicator > keyboard** and uncheck **"visible"**

Comment: For the record, this doesn't work anymore (I'm on 5.1 "Hera"), but the answer from [this question](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/10870/how-can-i-remove-the-keyboard-layout-icon-from-the-wingpanel/) does.