# How can I remove the keyboard layout icon from the wingpanel?

Tags: release-loki, release-juno, release-hera, wingpanel, keyboard-layout

I want to remove the keyboard layout icon from the wingpanel, a white block which is useless for me in there.

[image: image of my icons]

I have already tried [DConf-Tools](http://howtoelementaryos.org/how-to-install-dconf-tools-in-elementary-os) following the instructions given in this [answer](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2251/how-can-i-hide-the-keyboard-indicator-from-the-panel), yet I cannot make it work.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the keyboard indicator via the command line

```
sudo apt remove --purge wingpanel-indicator-keyboard
```

Or via any package manager remove the `wingpanel-indicator-keyboard` package.

Comment: It worked! Nice one mate.

Comment: this works! You can also use this to hide/remove other indicators example:
`sudo apt remove --purge wingpanel-indicator-power` removes power/brightness indicator

Comment: Just leaving a comment that this still works in 5.1 Hera. I'll add the Juno and Hera tags to the question to make this clearer to others.